# EDITED:: distinct multiple fields

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have this query

```
SELECT distinct username, time
FROM `sadaat`.`wp_loginlog`
where username != 'admin' or username is not null
order by time DESC
limit 0,20
```

This doesnt give me the distinct records. If I take out time then it does. What can I do to get distinct results there.

if I use

```
SELECT distinct username
FROM `sadaat`.`wp_loginlog`
where username != 'admin' or username is not null
order by time DESC
limit 0,20
```

then I can not get the value for time as it will not select the time field

Comment: It should give you all unique combinations of username, time. Can we see what it does give?

Comment: it gives everything..all the records within where clause.

Comment: please show us the full output, but make sure you really know what does DISTINCT refer to :)

Comment: as an OT, your where condition have a little error: even if you put the username != 'admin' condition, just because 'admin' IS not null it will match the second one, so row corresponding to the 'admin' user are selected (things I think you want to avoid). You probably have to change the 'or' into an 'and'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DISTINCT clause refer to all the attributes in the SELECT clause, not just username.
(actually, it does not make sense to have distinct username and non-distinct time).

For instance if you have row with the same username and different time they will always be displayed

Maybe, if you want some information about time relevant to each single user you can have a look at the  [group by clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: actually, in your table for each username i guess is defined more then one time, am I right? Can you please explain us wich of those time you want to pick? (the higher, the lower, an average?)

Answer (score 2):

Your current query is not working because `distinct` takes into account all the columns you are selecting.

If you want distinct usernames while including the `time` column, you can use `group by` with an aggregate for the `time` column, something like:

```
SELECT username, max(time)
FROM `sadaat`.`wp_loginlog` where username != 'admin' or username is not null
group by username
order by time DESC limit 0,20
```

Comment: max time will get you the maximum time recors. All I want is to have distinct names and then later select time to show in my code.

Comment: which time do you want to select? if you have multiple time you must choose which of them to select (if you want to use distinct). If you want to grab ALL of them you cannot use distinct nor group by.

Answer (score 0):

here is what did the trick

```
   SELECT *
    FROM `sadaat`.`wp_loginlog`
    where username != 'admin' or username is not null
Group By username
    order by time DESC
    limit 0,20
```